# How can I test error handing without try-- catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am writing code that validates texts. This is how I test it. But I don't want to use try--catch in unit testing. Please give me a better way to do it.

```
it('Testing if hook errors on invalid description.', async () => {
      try {
        workRequest.requestor = 'John';
        workRequest.description = 1;
        result = await app.service('dummy').create(workRequest);
      } catch (error) {
        assert.equal(error.errors.description, 'Description is must be a string');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

what you looking for is somthing like this 
**should.throws**
almost all tests framework supports this API

for example :

**shouldjs**

https://shouldjs.github.io/#should-throws

**mocha**

https://mochajs.org/#bdd

**and also**

https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_fn_error_message

```
 it('Testing if hook errors on invalid description.', async () => {
        assert.throws(  () =>  {
            workRequest.requestor = 'John';
            workRequest.description = 1;
            result = await app.service('dummy').create(workRequest);
        },
  err 
);
```

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript expert, but I've never seen the syntax of passing in a code block like that, does not have to be `() => { ... }` instead of `{ ... }`?

Comment: you are right thank you @Matthew . i updated my code

Comment: How I can know it sends a correct error message? Since I need to validate multi-elements

Comment: Just pass to err parameter the expected object